# How were Sirius Black and Barty Crouch Jr able to function inside Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

How were Sirius Black and Barty Crouch Jr. able to devise clever plans and escape when all other prisoners are practically lifeless?

Answer (score 11):

Sirius Black was able to escape because he was an animagus. Turning into a dog suppressed the influence of the Dementors. Also, the knowledge that he was innocent helped sustain him.

Barty Crouch Jr. didn't escape, so much as his mother used a polyjuice potion and swapped places with him and his father smuggled him out. As it says in *Goblet of Fire* the Dementors don't have eyes, and they felt one sickly person in a cell, and another entering and then leaving. They couldn't tell who was who (both were sickly and dying at the time).

Comment: You could also add that Sirius wasn't totally incapacitated as the other prisoners were because he was able to focus on his innocence and thus was able to muster the strength to change into his Animagus form.